Shadowing In blender
From the pictures, you will see in the left, that the shadows appear in the render engine EVEE. on the right it's on cycles, but it has no shadow detailing, I am using a plugin called stylized shading, and I want to imitate that shadowing but on cycles not in EVEE, what I am missing here.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

the material, that I am using is stylized shading, here's the link https://blendermarket.com/products/stylizedshaders
I know that EVEE is very different than cycles, but I want to know how to make the same results of evee in cycles, I want to make the same shadow detailing but in cycles NOT in EVEE. is there any tutorial that imitate that exactly ?

To replicate that result we would need to know exactly what it is doing. Since you did not provide a description of the process, nor show the node trees, and we can't easily access them because it is a commercial product, I don't think this question is answerable.
